# Running Python script based on Tshark output

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, tshark

I'm new to linux (playing with a RPi) and am trying to write a bash script (or any other method) to trigger a python script (which opens my garage door) when tshark reads a packet that contains my phones mac address (or static IP) and is type mgt subtype auth (phone joins the network).

I tried to achieve this project with nmap but cannot get my phone to respond to pings when the screen is off (but packets are sent when the screen is off and it joins the network :)

I have googled as hard as I know how to for the past week and haven't found any sort of example that triggers an event based on tsharks output in shell.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!
Ben

Comment: I got a script to work that scans for an authentication packet and when it receives one, opens a python script that interprets the packet. It seems that I was wrong about my assumption of sending the authentication packet when the screen is off and I still have to wake the phone up the phone and then I receive the authentication packet. If anyone has any ideas on how to get around this it would be much appreciated.


Here is the script that worked for me:

sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
while true
do
tshark -i mon0 -f "type mgt subtype auth" -c 1 > tshark.txt
python tsharkpython.py
done